# Spring Boot: Cannot access page html on localhost (404)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, http-error

I am trying to adapt the  Controller example on the Spring Boot website. Unfortunately I've got
the  **error 404** when I am trying to access the localhost:8080/NewFile URL

my EcomercController.java :

```
package com.techprimers.jpa.springjpahibernateexample.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class EcomercController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/NewFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String NewFile(){
         return "NewFile";
    }
}
```

and also i added this dependency in my porm.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and my path package

> com.exemple
>
> ----- com.exemple.web.EcomercController.java
>
> com.exemple.SpringJpaHibernateExampleApplication

and my file NewFile.html in

> resources->static->NewFile.html

Comment: Can you post the link of that example you are trying to replicate?

Comment: is it in the same package hierarchy as the class annotating `SpringApplication`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your html file in either of these-

```
src/main/resources/resources/index.html
src/main/resources/static/index.html 
src/main/resources/public/index.html
```

And since you opted for this-

```
src/main/resources/resources/index.html
```

Then place inside templates.

Answer (score 0):

Your html file should be inside `templates` folder

```
resources->templates->NewFile.html
```

Read [Spring Boot Serving static content](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)  to understand the resource mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Move your Html file into resources->templates folder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the applicaton configuration (under the resources folder) you have no context mapping. I think the default is "/api", in which case you'd need to access the URL as:

localhost:8080/api/NewFile

recommended: don't capitalize your URIs. use new-file or newfile instead.